# Do not collapse whitespace when displaying the value of the backing bean in the JSF

Tags: html, jsp, jsf, richfaces, whitespace

I found that the backing bean value displayed on the JSF page will collapse the white-space automatically .How can I make the value displayed do not collapse the white-space??

For example , I have a MBean which has a String variable `test` and assign the value

```
"test                  test"
```

, when I render it using `<h1>${MBean.test}</h1>` , it just give out `test test` which all the white-spaces in the middle collapse to a white-space only.

This behavior also happens if  I display the ArrayList from the MBean in the table format using the `<rich:dataTable>` , all the white-spaces will be collapsed too.

Updated: I still think that it is specific to the JSF , because when I use
`<h:inputText value="#{MBean.test}"/>` , the rendered input text box will collapse all the white-spaces.How can I preserve all the white-spaces in this case??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not specific to JSF. This is specific to HTML

You can fix it by *either* putting it in a HTML `<pre>` element:

```
<h1><pre>#{bean.text}</pre></h1>
```

*Or* by applying CSS [`white-space: pre`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html) on the HTML element:

```
h1 { 
    white-space: pre;
}
```

*(as you see, it also occurs on your question here on Stackoverflow as well, since it also doesn't preserve whitespace by `white-space: pre`)*

Comment: Yes ,`<h1><pre>#{bean.text}</pre></h1>` works !! Originally , I also used the css `white-space: pre ` approach `<h1 style="white-space:pre;" > #{bean.text}</h1> ` , but found that the HTML source rendered already collapse all the white-spaces.It seems JSF cannot handle `white-space: pre` properly??

Comment: Are you sure that it is been collapsed straight in the HTML source? This shouldn't happen.

Comment: Yes , `<h1 style="white-space:pre;" > #{bean.text}</h1>` will collapsed the string straight  in the HTML source , but `<h1><pre>#{bean.text}</pre></h1>` will not.

Comment: I still think that it is specific to the JSF , because when I use <h:inputText value="#{MBean.test}"/> , the rendered input text box will collapse all the white-spaces.

Comment: Doesn't occur here on Mojarra at all. Not in template text, not in `h:outputText`, not in `h:inputText`. Nowhere. It's maybe RichFaces specific (can't say a word about this since I don't use it) or you have some `Filter` in request-response chain which eats all the whitespace in order to save bandwidth and takes `<pre>` tags into account.

Comment: Yes , I am using RichFaces and have many filter in the application . Thanks for the insight given . I will try to see what the filter are doing in my application

Answer (score 0):

Sun's JavaServer Faces implementation (1.2_07-b03-FCS)  has the same issue on Webshpere Application Server 7.0.0.21 for the CSS white-space: pre